# Android Auto/Wear Custom Actions

Tags: android, wear-os, android-auto

After implementing MediaSession.Callback to add some custom actions to both Auto and Wear, I noticed that they expect very different types of icons.  On Auto the icons are supposed to be black and on Wear they are supposed to be white.  But there does not appear to be any way to differentiate the icons for different platforms.  I can specify a action either be or not be on Wear, but there is no way to do the same for Auto so I can't add the action twice with the two different icon styles.  I know this is somehow possible because Google Play Music is putting a custom white icon on Wear and a black icon on Auto correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking Google's sample application, the icon for starring appears to be pure white: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_star_off.png.  I have verified that if you make your icon pure white it will automatically be changed to black for use in Auto.  My best guess is that because Google wrote the stuff for Wear first they assumed that everyone's icons would be white already.